# how to pass an argument containing whitespace to a script containing gawk match()?

Tags: bash, awk, gawk

```
>gawk 'match("", "foo bar", junk)'
```

is a legitimate command, and I would like to pass the argument `foo bar` to it inside a shell script:

`foobar.sh` which has:

```
#!/bin/bash
gawk 'match("", "'$1'", junk)'
```

Does not work:

```
>./foobar.sh "foo bar"
gawk: match("", "foo
gawk:           ^ unterminated string
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be passed using `-v` option:

```
gawk -v arg="foo bar" 'match("", arg, junk)'
```

Answer (score 3):

You left out the quotes needed to avoid word-splitting:

```
gawk 'match("", "'"$1"'", junk)'
```

Without those quotes, the string is split into two words:

```
match("", "foo
bar", junk)
```

`awk` insists that the program be a single argument (the next argument will be treated as a filename), so that produces a syntax error, as observed.

This is not the best way to pass arbitrary strings into an awk script because it will fail if the string includes a quote or backslash. It is better to use the `-v var=value` command-line option to initialize an `awk` variable directly from a `bash` string, which does not involve actually parsing the string as part of an `awk` program. However, it is always useful to understand bash quoting.

Comment: Its not optimal way to read variable inn to `awk` this way.  Its better to use the  `-v` option.

Comment: @jotne, that is true but it should be explained. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes indeed I have a quote in there in the full example.  Thank you for all the answers.